# Script error unable to execute, Role Importer to creates roles for Idenititynow using Ruby Bulk AccessProfile and Role Importer

Tags: ruby, scripting, roles

```
oles-name.csv (Errno::EINVAL)csv.rb:1593:in `initialize': Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:Role-ImporterRole-Importer
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/csv.rb:1593:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/csv.rb:1593:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/csv.rb:1333:in `foreach'
        from roleImporter.rb:874:in `<main>'
```

I tried configuring my roles format, tried various ways but for some reason it doesn't move from that.
Just wondering how we can go and work through it.

##### Create Access Profile with Attribute Type

For creating Access Profiles where the attribute needs to be specified in case multiple entitlements for the same source exist that have the same display name but different attributes, order of column in the row will be as below

```
createAccessProfileWithAttributeType,Name of Access Profile,Description,Source,attributeName,';' separated Entitlement Name list, AccesProfile Owner, AccessProfile Approvers List, Required Denied Comments, Required User Request Comments,Revoke Request Approval Schemes 
createAccessProfileWithAttributeType, Example Access Profile, This is another Example Access Profile, Active Directory, memberOf, Entitlement1;Entitlement2, slpt.services, "manager,sourceOwner,accessProfileOwner,appOwner,GovernanceGroupName", true/false, true/false,"manager,sourceOwner,accessProfileOwner,appOwner,GovernanceGroupName"
```

First five column values are Required while last five column values (AccesProfile Owner, AccessProfile Approvers List, Required Denied Comments, Required User Request Comments,Revoke Request Approval Schemes ) are optional for createAccessProfileWithAttributeType

Note: **Entitlement list list should be separated by semicolon ';' NOT by Comma.**

##### Create Role

For creating Roles order of column in the row will be as below

```
createRole, Role Name, Role Description,roleDisabled(true/false),Role Owner,';' separated Access Profile Name list,requestable(true/false),Role Approvers List,Required Denied Comments,Required User Request Comments,revokeRequestApprovalSchemes 
createRole, Example Role,This is an Example Role,TRUE,slpt.services,ExampleAccessProfile;AccessPExample,true/false,"manager,owner,Governance group Name",true/false,true/false,"manager,owner,Governance group Name"
```